# Send thank you email to every user creating an article in MediaWiki

Tags: php, email, mediawiki

I want my MediaWiki to send a 'Thank You' mail to the author when he creates a new article. 
Is any extension available for this method?

Alternatively: I am creating article from a special page. So it is possible to add my own extension and write an email script. But I am confused how to get the email ID of the author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`UserMailer`](http://svn.wikimedia.org/doc/classUserMailer.html) and [`MailAddress`](http://svn.wikimedia.org/doc/classMailAddress.html) classes:

```
global $wgPasswordSender, $wgPasswordSenderName;

$from = new MailAddress( $wgPasswordSender, $wgPasswordSenderName );
$to = new MailAddress( $user );

$subject = "Thank you!";
$text = "This is a test. Blah blah blah...";

$status = UserMailer::send( $to, $from, $subject, $text );

if ( $status->isGood() ) {
    // Great, it worked!
} else {
    // Something went wrong, deal with it...
    // The $status object will have more information.
}
```

The `MailAddress` constructor takes either a `User` object or an address and a name.  [`$wgPasswordSender`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgPasswordSender) is the default e-mail address used by MediaWiki for sending password reset e-mails and other such things; you've hopefully configured it in your `LocalSetting.php`.

Comment: Thanks Man.. This code worked !!!!
I added this code under 'Create Article Hook' and placed this in Hook.php.. Worked like charm.. Thanks a ton !!